# How to communicate between Java and bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, java, scala

I am having problems communicating between Java and bitcoind - every JSON RPC library I try has some issues. Can anyone provide a working implementation of even the most basic JSON RPC communication between Java and bitcoind ?

Comment: There's a bitcoin library for java... That could be why few people are working on a JSON RPC for java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here's an early experimental client I had played around with a while back](https://github.com/cdelargy/BitcoinRPCClient/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cdelargy/bitcoin/RPCClient.java). It supports getInfo, getBalance and getNewAddress, and can easily be expanded. In order to run it, the credentials for your local bitcoind have to match the values in the client class:

```
httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("localhost", 8332),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("btc", "123"));
```

Feel free to use this code in any way, but understand that it's only 5 minutes of work on a start, not a realistic client implementation. Hope it helps you generate some ideas!

Comment: I like this solution a lot, the only issue is that the first call on this client takes very long. A 'getrawtransaction' call on my laptop takes 288 ms suing this http client while running a process from Java takes ~ 5 ms. However, this client is more efficient in the long run taking about 4 ms on average for all other calls. I tried to speed it up by trying to use cookie authentification but was not able... Solutions to this problem are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You are also very welcome to try out https://github.com/clanie/bitcoind-client - it is in early development, but already supports almost all the methods provided by bitcoind.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and created an implementation here: https://github.com/johannbarbie/BitcoindClient4J

Answer (score 3):

Because this seems like a collection of links, I will just add another one:

https://github.com/priiduneemre/btcd-cli4j

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/nitinsurana/Litecoin-Bitcoin-RPC-Java-Connector

It uses Htmlunit instead of Apache Http Library, which makes it a bit easy to understand and extend.

I actually wrote & tested it for Litecoin for one of my projects. But it has been extended to support bitcoin and all the RPC methods are available.

Answer (score 2):

Library under Apache Licence:
https://github.com/SulacoSoft/BitcoindConnector4J

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not find working code snippet anywhere, here is a complete working example (in Scala):

First I created a helper object:

```
import java.net.URL
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

object CurlJsonData {
  def curl(url:String, jsonEncodedString:String) = {
    val httpcon = new URL(url).openConnection.asInstanceOf[HttpURLConnection]
    httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpcon.connect;

    val outputBytes = jsonEncodedString.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // 'using' method from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5218279/243233

    using(httpcon.getOutputStream){os =>
      os.write(outputBytes)
    }
    val code = httpcon.getResponseCode
    val isError = code >= 400 && code <= 500
    val resp = using{
      if (isError) httpcon.getErrorStream else httpcon.getInputStream
    }{is =>
      val writer = new StringWriter;
      IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
      writer.toString;
    }
    httpcon.disconnect
    if (isError) throw new Exception(
      s"Resp code $code. Error: ${resp.take(200)}"
    ) else resp
  }
}
```

Then, I used it as follows:

```
import java.net.Authenticator
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication

val rpcuser = "alice";
val rpcpassword = "secret";

Authenticator.setDefault(
  new Authenticator {
    override def getPasswordAuthentication:PasswordAuthentication = {
      new PasswordAuthentication (rpcuser, rpcpassword.toCharArray)
    }
  }
)  

CurlJsonData.curl(
  "http://localhost:8332", 
  """{"method":"getblockchaininfo","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"1.0"}"""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems of Java is the verbosity of the language. However, it is also true that the life of the language it is very old in these that.

I fall into the problem to talk with the bitcoin rpc interface for one of my side projects on c-lightning and I was not able to find a clean library that is able to talk also with other rpc interfaces derived from bitcoin core, like litecoin. In addition, I found also a library that is easy like a python library.

My result of designing a library that respect this requirement, it is called lite-bitcoin-rpc and it is available on GitHub https://github.com/clightning4j/lite-bitcoin-rpc

This is an easy library because with gives the possibility to write the JSON wrapper in a Java class and use it to decode the response. The end-user need only to feel a map with parameters and create the Java class where decode the JSON payload received from bitcoin core.

An example can be found in the test directory https://github.com/clightning4j/lite-bitcoin-rpc/tree/main/lib/src/test

and a code example can be

```
public class LiteBitcoinRPCTest {

  private LiteBitcoinRPC bitcoinRPC;

  public LiteBitcoinRPCTest() {
    this.bitcoinRPC = new LiteBitcoinRPC("sandbox", "sandbox", "http://127.0.0.1:18333/");
  }

  @Test
  public void getBlockchainInfo() {
    try {
      BlockchainInfo info =
          bitcoinRPC.makeBitcoinRequest("getblockchaininfo", BlockchainInfo.class);
      TestCase.assertEquals(info.getChain(), "regtest");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      TestCase.fail(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void estimateFeeRateWithError() {
    Parameters parameters = new Parameters("estimatesmartfee");
    parameters.addParameter("conf_target", 6);
    try {
      BitcoinEstimateFee feee = bitcoinRPC.makeBitcoinRequest(parameters, BitcoinEstimateFee.class);
      TestCase.assertFalse(feee.getErrors().isEmpty());
    } catch (LiteBitcoinRPCException | BitcoinCoreException e) {
      TestCase.fail(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Scala is not your thing, here is Jus12's code in Kotlin:

```
package com.my.blockchainparser

import java.net.Authenticator
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication
import java.net.URL
import java.net.HttpURLConnection

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val rpcuser = "user"
    val rpcpassword = "password"
    Authenticator.setDefault(object : Authenticator() {
        override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
            return PasswordAuthentication(rpcuser, rpcpassword.toCharArray())
        }
    })

    System.out.println(curl(
            "http://localhost:8332",
            """{"method":"getblockchaininfo","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"1.0"}"""
    ))
}

fun curl(url:String, jsonEncodedString:String): String {
    val httpcon = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpcon.connect();

    val outputBytes = jsonEncodedString.toByteArray();

    httpcon.getOutputStream().use {
        it.write(outputBytes)
    }
    val code = httpcon.getResponseCode()
    val isError = code >= 400 && code <= 500
    val text = (if (isError) httpcon.getErrorStream() else httpcon.getInputStream())
            ?.bufferedReader()?.use {
        it.readText()
    } ?: "no connection"
    if (isError) throw Exception(
            "Resp code $code. Error: ${text.take(200)}"
    )
    return text
}
```