# Can i create wallet services of bitcoin core wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Is it possible to create wallet url services for bitcoin core wallet

Comment: There is no clear definition of "wallet service". Core offers an RPC interface which is  kind of a wallet service.

Comment: URL services of wallet so that i can run in web

Comment: It's still very unclear what you mean. You want to access it in a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Is it possible to create wallet url services for bitcoin core wallet**

Yes it is possible.

It is possible because Bitcoin core has a [Remote Procedure Call (RPC) interface](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)) usable with many different programming languages, including those popular for creating back-end web-services accessible from web-browsers.

The [developer reference](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference) says:

> The Bitcoin Core RPC service listens for HTTP POST requests on port 8332 in mainnet mode or 18332 in testnet or regtest mode. The port number can be changed by setting rpcport in bitcoin.conf. By default the RPC service binds to your server’s localhost loopback network interface so it’s not accessible from other servers. Authentication is implemented using HTTP basic authentication. RPC HTTP requests must include a Content-Type header set to text/plain and a Content-Length header set to the size of the request body.
>
> The format of the request body and response data is based on version 1.0 of the JSON-RPC specification. Specifically, the HTTP POST data of a request must be a JSON object

Exactly how you would write new software to use this is a software-development/programming question. For example see [How to communicate between Java and bitcoind?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/7529/13866)

> **URL services of wallet so that i can run in web**

No, the API is RPC based. Maybe you are looking for something with a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) interface accessible from an ordinary web-browser or a ready-made custodial-wallet HTTP service - in that case I suggest searching using an Internet search engine of your choice.